# ERROR in VGGnet CNN / Import ERROR: import tflearn.datasets.oxflower17 as oxflower17

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

getting this error in the Code:

```
import tflearn.datasets.oxflower17 as oxflower17
from keras.utils import to_categorical

x, y = oxflower17.load_data()`your text`

x_train = x.astype('float32') / 255.0
y_train = to_categorical(y, num_classes=17)
```

ERROR:

ImportError: cannot import name 'is_sequence' from 'tensorflow.python.util.nest' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py)

Try to update the tensorflow by: pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Also try reinstalling the tensorflow but it didn't work.

[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiVeR.jpg)